# How to do multiple replace in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have code as below:

```
s = pd.Series(['$2.75', np.nan, 4.150000, 25.00, '$4.50','k876','g67.3'])

strs =  s.astype(str).str.replace("$", "").replace("k", "").replace("g", "")
#strs = s.astype(str).str.replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True)
res = pd.to_numeric(strs, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
print(res)
```

I suppose output should be:

```
0     2.75
1     0.00
2     4.15
3    25.00
4     4.50
5     876
6     67.3
```

But instead, row 5 and 6 actually result is zero.

Please help point out the mistake. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regex=True` in your `replace` codes, like below

```
s = pd.Series(['$2.75', np.nan, 4.150000, 25.00, '$4.50','k876','g67.3'])
strs =  s.astype(str).str.replace("$", "", regex=True).replace("k", "", regex=True).replace("g", "", regex=True)
res = pd.to_numeric(strs, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0      2.75
1      0.00
2      4.15
3     25.00
4      4.50
5    876.00
6     67.30
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can you please check again? it is working for me on the input you provided. I have pasted the output as well.

Comment: [Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qk9d9zwr72xcgn6/60597472%2360597472-1.png?dl=0)
I am using colab. python version have difference result ?

Comment: in your last line, you still have variable `strs` change it to `str` because you have named the new variable `str`. By the way, avoid us `str` as variable. It is better to use `strs` itself. Full code included in the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use `str.strip` or `str.lstrip`

**Ex:**

```
s = pd.Series(['$2.75', np.nan, 4.150000, 25.00, '$4.50','k876','g67.3'])
strs =  s.astype(str).str.strip("$kg")
res = pd.to_numeric(strs, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
0      2.75
1      0.00
2      4.15
3     25.00
4      4.50
5    876.00
6     67.30
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with pattern `([\d\.]+)` (one or more consecutive digit or `.`):

```
res = pd.to_numeric(s.astype(str).str.extract(r'([\d\.]+)')[0], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

[out]

```
0      2.75
1      0.00
2      4.15
3     25.00
4      4.50
5    876.00
6     67.30
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```